# Java GC CMS Pause Time increasing over time

Tags: java, garbage-collection

we have an issue where approx over an 8 hour interval..our nodes GC pause time increases, where it finally gets a its longest pause time ~0.8-1.2second (a full gc)..and then it drops back down to about ~0.1 seconds or and resumes it 8 hour..cycle..

The wave pattern on ~8 hours we see consistently on both 2 core boxes, and 4 core boxes, the 4 core boxes tend to have smaller pauses on average but the spikes are the same, i.e. just as bad on our 2 core boxes.

Clearly when our GC is running its not doing enough on each run, since we continue to see the heap/pause times increasing over 8 hours..so my question is how can we force the GC cycle to be more effective..instead of waiting until it needs a long full gc cycle.  (I suppose cutting the heap i half..would force it to run more often..hopefully resulting in 'half' the pause time spikes..but that is not ideal)

(PS we are running these jvms on java 8,4GB boxes).
Objects created are typically short lived (the system essentially represents a queue lots of object in, lots of object out..typically within seconds..its just constant flow of objects, cpu usage is 'low').

Our GC parameters

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+UseThreadPriorities
-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42
-Xms3000M
-Xmx3000M
-Xmn1500M
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Xss256k
-XX:StringTableSize=1000003
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem
-XX:CompileCommandFile=./../conf/hotspot_compiler
-XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000
-XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled
-XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways
-XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000
-XX:+UseCondCardMark
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
-Xloggc:/logs/gc.log
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:GCLogFileSize=100M
```

GC Log snippet of 2 events showing long gc (and long scrub string table on cms-remark final), the 2nd event we see what I believe is very high class unloading time as well..(we don't do any dynamic loading of classes).

```
2018-07-17T06:20:43.738+0000: 33759.362: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1154831K(1536000K)] 1165177K(2918400K), 0.0048510 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2018-07-17T06:20:43.743+0000: 33759.367: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0082435 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:43.743+0000: 33759.367: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2018-07-17T06:20:43.836+0000: 33759.460: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.093/0.093 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs] 
2018-07-17T06:20:43.836+0000: 33759.460: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2018-07-17T06:20:43.844+0000: 33759.468: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.007/0.008 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2018-07-17T06:20:43.844+0000: 33759.468: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-17T06:20:48.887+0000: 33764.511: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 4.699/5.043 secs] [Times: user=5.58 sys=0.02, real=5.04 secs] 

 2018-07-17T06:20:48.892+0000: 33764.517: [GC (CMS Final Remark) 
    [YG occupancy: 89219 K (1382400 K)]
    33764.517: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0256303 secs]
    33764.543: [weak refs processing, 0.0124976 secs]
    33764.555: [class unloading, 0.0593605 secs]
    33764.615: [scrub symbol table, 0.0028103 secs]
    33764.617: [scrub string table, 0.3960129 secs]
    [1 CMS-remark: 1154831K(1536000K)] 
    1244051K(2918400K), 0.5055637 secs] 
    [Times: user=0.58 sys=0.00, real=0.50 secs] 
2018-07-17T06:20:49.399+0000: 33765.023: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.5111839 seconds

2018-07-17T06:20:49.399+0000: 33765.023: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2018-07-17T06:20:49.408+0000: 33765.032: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0034313 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.411+0000: 33765.035: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0022739 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.415+0000: 33765.039: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0022818 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.418+0000: 33765.042: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0020566 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.420+0000: 33765.044: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0017496 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.423+0000: 33765.047: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0022639 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.425+0000: 33765.049: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0016516 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.427+0000: 33765.051: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0018342 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.429+0000: 33765.053: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015327 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.430+0000: 33765.054: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015723 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.432+0000: 33765.056: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015356 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.433+0000: 33765.058: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0014560 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.436+0000: 33765.060: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0019394 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.437+0000: 33765.061: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015594 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:49.460+0000: 33765.084: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0028257 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:50.464+0000: 33766.088: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0031651 seconds
2018-07-17T06:20:50.702+0000: 33766.326: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.269/1.303 secs] [Times: user=1.58 sys=0.00, real=1.31 secs] 
2018-07-17T06:20:50.702+0000: 33766.326: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2018-07-17T06:20:50.706+0000: 33766.330: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.004/0.004 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2018-07-17T06:20:51.469+0000: 33767.093: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0046566 seconds



2018-07-22T19:38:00.619+0000: 513596.243: [GC (CMS Final Remark) 
     [YG occupancy: 56180 K (1382400 K)]
        513596.243: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0230426 secs]
        513596.266: [weak refs processing, 0.0272667 secs]
        513596.293: [class unloading, 0.1770894 secs]
        513596.471: [scrub symbol table, 0.0101295 secs]
        513596.481: [scrub string table, 0.3882333 secs]
        [1 CMS-remark: 1152442K(1536000K)] 1208623K(2918400K), 0.6355867 secs] [Times: user=0.56 sys=0.00, real=0.63 secs] 
2018-07-22T19:38:01.255+0000: 513596.879: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.6396559 seconds


2018-07-22T19:37:55.241+0000: 513590.865: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1152442K(1536000K)] 1173594K(2918400K), 0.0309287 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2018-07-22T19:37:55.272+0000: 513590.896: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0344867 seconds
2018-07-22T19:37:55.272+0000: 513590.896: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2018-07-22T19:37:55.443+0000: 513591.067: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.170/0.170 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.17 secs] 
2018-07-22T19:37:55.443+0000: 513591.067: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2018-07-22T19:37:55.451+0000: 513591.075: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.007/0.008 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2018-07-22T19:37:55.451+0000: 513591.075: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2018-07-22T19:38:00.615+0000: 513596.239: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 3.434/5.164 secs] [Times: user=4.10 sys=0.11, real=5.16 secs] 

2018-07-22T19:38:00.619+0000: 513596.243: [GC (CMS Final Remark) 
     [YG occupancy: 56180 K (1382400 K)]
        513596.243: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0230426 secs]
        513596.266: [weak refs processing, 0.0272667 secs]
        513596.293: [class unloading, 0.1770894 secs]
        513596.471: [scrub symbol table, 0.0101295 secs]
        513596.481: [scrub string table, 0.3882333 secs]
        [1 CMS-remark: 1152442K(1536000K)] 1208623K(2918400K), 0.6355867 secs] [Times: user=0.56 sys=0.00, real=0.63 secs] 

2018-07-22T19:38:01.255+0000: 513596.879: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.6396559 seconds
2018-07-22T19:38:01.255+0000: 513596.880: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2018-07-22T19:38:02.209+0000: 513597.833: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.953/0.953 secs] [Times: user=1.10 sys=0.00, real=0.96 secs] 
2018-07-22T19:38:02.209+0000: 513597.833: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2018-07-22T19:38:02.213+0000: 513597.837: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.003/0.003 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2018-07-22T19:38:02.260+0000: 513597.884: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0045430 seconds
```

Comment: What version of Java?   Java 1.8?  Minor version? I suggest trying the G1 collector instead.

Comment: If you have GC logs then you should post them too. It's silly to capture stats and then withhold them when asking a question.

Comment: Fair enough, I might be able to provide a GC log come Monday.  We tried G1..it was worse :(  Java 1.8 various revisions, we have a mix of versions for testing..all exhibit the same pattern..will get those details on Monday as well)

Comment: I have uploaded a gc log from one of our 4 core boxes, where see the the zig-zag pattern, with long pauses at the peaks...naturally we want to avoid the long pauses: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CE-YheKLWXfcaCBWgIy0wZk5TgOtoDwj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: on thing I did notice, it appears that the CMS Final Remark phase, is spending most of its time on scrub string table, 0.3960129 secs..this often times represents 60-70% of the long pauses, as such re-running tests now with: -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are interning too many strings. why do you need a intern String table size of 1 Million? Strings that die young and could be cleaned by a young collection should not be interned. Only Strings that most likely survive an old generation collection should be interned. Or do you need the memory savings of interning so many strings?

Comment: In general, answers are expected to be useful without asking for clarification from the asker. The questions in your answer should probably be comments instead.